# Xcode 8 GM upload app to iTunes Connect issue

Tags: itunes, testflight

I use Xcode 8GM for build & upload app to iTunes Connect (Testflight). No error messages, no warnings, no e-mails from apple team but after 'Processing' status on iTunes connect I see red badge with exclamation point as status of my build. Third-party libraries are: Google Maps, Google plus, VK-, FB- SDKs. No bit code enabled, no private API used.
The only message that I can see on iTunes Connect is 'There was an error importing this build.'

Someone faced with such a situation the last 3-4 days? Can I see where a reason for rejection of my application?

TNX

Comment: Are you using Sierra?

Comment: I am also experiencing this...have you arrived at a solution? I tried re-uploading with new version and build numbers. Also changed target to iOS 10, but that did not help either.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. It submits successfully but when watching into itunes connect, there appears no build submitted. I tried by creating new profile and certificates but same results.